# Angular 5 need to compute a property in component

Tags: typescript, angular5

I'm very new to Angular 5, find it rather tedious how hard everything is compared to something elegant like VueJS.

Nevertheless I need to learn it. I need to create a composite name in my model in the controller, or perhaps in a model, but I haven't figured out how to connect one up.

The following code compiles but just gives me a blank page, no errors:

```
export class AppComponent {

    editMode =  false;
    name = { prefix: "Mr.", first: "John", mi: "K", last: "Smith" };
    namePrefix = [
      {key: "-1", text: ""},
      {key: "0", text: "Mr."},
      {key: "1", text: "Ms."},
      {key: "2", text: "Mrs."},
      {key: "3", text: "Dr."}
    ];
    attributes = ["1", "5", "7"];
    links = ["http://google.com", "https://connect.cray.us.com", "http://yahoo.com"];
    position = [ "First Position", "Position Two", "3rd Position"];
    topThree = [ "Yadda", "Badda", "Bing"];
    attribList = [
      {key: "1", text: "Attribute of first kind"},
      {key: "2", text: "Important Attribute"},
      {key: "3", text: "Really important attribute"},
      {key: "4", text: "Blue suede shoes"},
      {key: "5", text: "Back dimension"},
      {key: "6", text: "Front dimension"},
      {key: "7", text: "Forward dimension"},
      {key: "8", text: "Fifth dimension"},
      {key: "9", text: "One less egg to fry"}
    ];

    fullUserName = this.getFullUserName();

    //if I delete this and directly assign the value, it runs:  
    getFullUserName() {
      var result = [];
      var props = ['prefix', 'first', 'mi', 'last'];
      for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
         var prop = props[i];
         var item = this.name[prop];
         if (item !== "") {
            if (prop === "mi") {
               item += ".";
            }
            result.push(item);
         }
      }
      return result.join(' ');
    }


    toEditMode() {
      this.editMode = true;
    }

    cancel() {
      this.editMode = false;
    }

    save() {
      this.editMode = false;
    }

};
```

This is the template, as if it matters:

```
<div class="centeredLayout">
    <div class="profile" id="profile">
        <header>
            <h1>User Profile</h1>
            <div class="buttons">
                <button *ngIf="!editMode" (click)="toEditMode()">Edit</button>
                <button *ngIf="editMode" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
                <button *ngIf="editMode" (click)="save()">Save</button>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="control name">
                <label>Employee Name</label>
                <div *ngIf="editMode" class="float">
                    <div class="control small">
                        <label>Prefix</label>
                        <select [value]="name.prefix">
                            <ng-template *ngFor="let item of namePrefix">
                                <option [value]="item.text" >{{item.text}}</option>
                            </ng-template>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control medium">
                        <label>First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" [value]="name.first" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="control short">
                        <label>MI</label>
                        <input type="text" [value]="name.mi" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="control medium">
                        <label>Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" [value]="name.last" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p *ngIf="!editMode">{{fullUserName}}</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="control fullWidth">
                    <label>Attributes</label>
                    <div class="multiselect" *ngIf="editMode">
                        <label *ngFor="let item of attribList">
                            <input type="checkbox" [value]="item.key" ngModel="attributes" /><span>{{item.text}}</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf ="!editMode" class="list">
                        <ng-template *ngIf="item.key in attributes"></ng-template>
                        <p *ngFor="let item of attribList">{{item.text}}</p> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control fullWidth">
                    <label>Top Three</label>
                    <ng-template *ngIf ="editMode">
                        <input *ngFor="let item of topThree" type="text" :data-index="index" [value]="item" v-on:keyup="updateTopThree"/>
                    </ng-template>
                    <div *ngIf ="!editMode" class="list">
                        <p *ngFor="let item of topThree" >{{item}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="control">
                <label class="withButton">Position</label>
                <button *ngIf="editMode" v-on:click="addPosition">Add</button>
                <ul *ngIf ="!editMode">
                    <li *ngFor="let item of position">{{item}}</li>
                </ul>
                <div *ngIf="editMode">
                    <div class="group" *ngFor="let item of position">
                        <input :data-index="index" type="text" [value]="item" v-on:keyup="updatePosition" /><button v-on:click="removePosition" class="symbol" :data-index="index">r</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control full">
                <label>Links</label>
                    <ng-template *ngIf="editMode">
                        <input *ngFor="let item of links" :data-index="index" [value]="item"  
                    v-on:keyup="updateLinks" />
                    </ng-template>
                <div class="list" *ngIf="!editMode">
                    <p *ngFor="let item of links"><a :href="item">{{ item}}</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A better template, it still doesn't do a lot of the things I want, but that is a different question. I'm not sure why the template didn't like the function to assign the value, but once fixed the component code worked properly.

```
<div class="centeredLayout">
    <div class="profile" id="profile">
        <header>
            <h1>User Profile</h1>
            <div class="buttons">
                <button *ngIf="!editMode" (click)="toEditMode()">Edit</button>
                <button *ngIf="editMode" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
                <button *ngIf="editMode" (click)="save()">Save</button>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="control name">
                <label>Employee Name</label>
                <div *ngIf="editMode" class="float">
                    <div class="control small">
                        <label>Prefix</label>
                        <select [value]="name.prefix">
                            <ng-template *ngFor="let item of namePrefix">
                                <option [value]="item.text" >{{item.text}}</option>
                            </ng-template>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control medium">
                        <label>First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" [value]="name.first" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="control short">
                        <label>MI</label>
                        <input type="text" [value]="name.mi" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="control medium">
                        <label>Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" [value]="name.last" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p *ngIf="!editMode">{{fullUserName}}</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="control fullWidth">
                    <label>Attributes</label>
                    <div class="multiselect" *ngIf="editMode">
                        <label *ngFor="let item of attribList">
                            <input type="checkbox" [value]="item.key" /><span>{{item.text}}</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="!editMode" class="list">
                        <ng-template *ngFor="let item of attribList">
                            <p>{{item.text}}</p> 
                        </ng-template>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control fullWidth">
                    <label>Top Three</label>
                    <ng-template *ngIf ="editMode">
                        <input *ngFor="let item of topThree" type="text" :data-index="index" [value]="item" v-on:keyup="updateTopThree"/>
                    </ng-template>
                    <div *ngIf ="!editMode" class="list">
                        <p *ngFor="let item of topThree" >{{item}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="control">
                <label class="withButton">Position</label>
                <button *ngIf="editMode" v-on:click="addPosition">Add</button>
                <ul *ngIf ="!editMode">
                    <li *ngFor="let item of position">{{item}}</li>
                </ul>
                <div *ngIf="editMode">
                    <div class="group" *ngFor="let item of position">
                        <input :data-index="index" type="text" [value]="item" v-on:keyup="updatePosition" /><button v-on:click="removePosition" class="symbol" :data-index="index">r</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control full">
                <label>Links</label>
                    <ng-template *ngIf="editMode">
                        <input *ngFor="let item of links" :data-index="index" [value]="item"  
                    v-on:keyup="updateLinks" />
                    </ng-template>
                <div class="list" *ngIf="!editMode">
                    <p *ngFor="let item of links"><a :href="item">{{ item}}</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And the template is?

Comment: The template is irrelevant because if I set fullUserName = "Yadda badda bing"; it works and is written on the page. But I will add it to the post.

Comment: It does matter. You said "I have a blank page". How could we know why you have a blank page if we don't even know what your template is doing Maybe you have a blank page because there's nothing in your template. Maybe because you have everything inside an ngIf with a false condition. Your template is a mix of angular and vue markup. It has invalid ng-templates that do cause error messages: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qdctmr. Removing these ng-templates causes the page to be displayed: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gporxp?file=src/app/app.component.html.

Comment: I said it worked if I didn't use the function to build the composite name field. I know there is still some vueJS stuff in the template but it is being ignored by angular at the moment. I left it in there to have a guide on where to put things later.

Comment: So, what is the precise code that doesn't work as you want, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Be precise. We can't guess what you mean. We can't see the code that you don't post.